# Sharepoint online follow site not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, modern-experience, communication-site, following

I have a SharePoint Modern Communication site that has "follow" button.  This button is not working for few users.  They see the "Follow" option, but on clicking the button, nothing happens.

I am getting the following error in console:

> https://root/sitecollurl/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/followed/add 500 (Internal Server error)

They are not able to follow a site from `https://root/_layouts/sharepoint.aspx` as well.

Any known issues with follow option?

**Following Content** feature is active.

Comment: Can you please try deactivating and again activating the `Following Content` feature on a site level??

Comment: Can you log in with their account and test at your end to see the result? Also switching to another browser would be an option.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Switching to browser or even the machine and deactivating&activating the feature didn't had any effect.  This is happening across all the site collections and I am able to follow/unfollow when logged in using the same browser in the user's machine.

Comment: Can you please check whether My sites are created for the particular user

Answer (score 0):

Please try to disable the limited user access lockdown mode site feature. Generally 500 errors in SPO trace back to permissions related issues. See more here:

https://albandrodsmemory.wordpress.com/2018/02/05/internal-server-error-while-creating-sharepoint-online-team-site/

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if any styles, scripts or any assets tied to that page with the button ( especially any external scripts ) may have limited permissions to most of the group but not everyone. This has happened to me a while back.

Also you can test this by creating a sample button in a general area ( with broad permissions ) and see if those who couldn't access the other "button" can make this sample button work.

Another thing to check: those who can't get he button to work, have they ever had any of your buttons work for them before ( ask and see ). They may have their browsers blocking scripts.

Gather info from at least 5 users with the issue and cross reference their browsers, browser version and /or department ( checking for group permissioning )

As a "band-aid" until you get it fixed. See if you can make a hyperlink under the button for those who can't use the button.

Hope you get it sorted out dude.

Answer (score 0):

The *follow* feature has a dependency on the OneDrive service as well - I'd suggest checking that if the sites and libraries concerned have not been locked down or had any features deactivated etc. have you verified that OneDrive is enabled - including that users have a OneDrive license enabled, OneDrive site and OneDrive client etc.? Check the user and license syncing for any errors that may suggest this as a possible cause.